# Why import can be used in this commonjs module?

Tags: javascript, import, require, commonjs, esmodules

Code is here: https://github.com/timewalker08/wechaty-test/tree/master

According to [nodejs document](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/esm.html#esm_package_json_type_field):

> If the nearest parent package.json lacks a "type" field, or contains "type": "commonjs", .js files are treated as CommonJS. If the volume root is reached and no package.json is found, Node.js defers to the default, a package.json with no "type" field.

There is no "type" field in package.json, so it is treated as CommonJS.

However, in file https://github.com/timewalker08/wechaty-test/blob/master/src/wechat-bot.ts, import was used to import module instead of require.

Why? As far as I know, import cannot be used in CommonJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short Answer

TypeScript will generate `wechat-bot.js` as CommonJS by converting `import` to `require`, and the code will work when there is no `type` field in `package.json`.

### Explanation

The example code file is a TypeScript (.ts) file. `tsc` command will compile it into JavaScript during the build step. If the code works, the generated JavaScript (.js) files have `require` instead of `import`.

Generated JavaScript depends on your `tsconfg.json`, but the example repo didn't have the `tsconfg.json` file.

If the `tsconfg.json` file has the [module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module) as `CommonJS` or [target](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target) as `ES3` or `ES5`, then TypeScript generates CommonJS module and converts `import` statements to `require` statements in the generated JavaScript.